How to assign shorter names to all of your columns without having to rename them automatically?
I got a dataset of 300ish columns and all of them are just very long questions, which makes any data management super tedious. I would like to rename all these columns to give them a shorter names but given there are 300 of them, I cannot see myself do it manually.
Here is a short example of what I would like to achieve.
My data frame looks like this :
col_names <- c("How old are your parents ?", "How old is your sister ?", 
          "What dessert did you eat yesterday ? [Option1]",  "What dessert did you eat yesterday ? [Option2]",
          "What dessert did you eat yesterday ? [Option3]", "What color is your shirt ? [Option 1]", 
          "What color is your shirt ? [Option 2]")

data <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(col_names), nrow = 2))
colnames(data) <- col_names

I would like to know if there is a way to rename my columns in an automatic way, but which could also take into account the fact that some columns have almost the same names, and are just variations of each other, like this :
col_names <- c("A", "B", 
               "C[Option1]",  "C[Option2]","C[Option3]", "D[Option 1]", 
               "D[Option 2]")

data <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(col_names), nrow = 2))
colnames(data) <- col_names

Bonus question, but would there be any way to rename them like this :
col_names <- c("A", "B", 
               "C1",  "C2","C3", "D1", 
               "D2")

data <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(col_names), nrow = 2))
colnames(data) <- col_names

Thank you in advance.

If you can think of a function to create new names from the old ones, there's dplyr::rename_with(). I think you need to identify the best pattern on your questions and try to work it out. Something like "What dessert did you eat yesterday ?" turns to "what_dessert_yesterday" (pronoum+noum or fist and second words plus the last one) and "What color is your shirt ? [Option 1]" into "what_color_shirt_01". How about that?

Or just give a number to them, like q_001, q_002 .. q_300. Questions with multiple options being q_271_op_001, q_271_op_002.

The second solution could do the trick, could you show me the code to do it with my example, if it's not too much to ask ?

Frame challenge: consider pivoting your data from wide to long.  Your new data frame would have columns, for, say, respondent id, date, question group, question (text or id) and response.  You then select questions by filtering and your downstream code becomes more robust (because it doesn't depend on column names) and likely more compact because you can rely on by group processing.

@Adriano Mello is right, this is the way to go.
Here is a code based on the sample you've provided - I didn't do any smart word removal but it should give you a good idea if you like it:
require(stopwords)
require(tidyverse)
col_names <- c("How old are your parents ?", "How old is your sister ?", 
               "What dessert did you eat yesterday ? [Option1]",  "What dessert did you eat yesterday ? [Option2]",
               "What dessert did you eat yesterday ? [Option3]", "What color is your shirt ? [Option 1]", 
               "What color is your shirt ? [Option 2]")


# take a string and remove all words that are in the stopwords list
  # transform [option{\\d}] to \\d

remove_stopwords <- function(string){
  string <- tolower(string)
  # extract & remove option
  d <- str_extract(string,"(\\d)")
  words <- str_extract(string,"[^(\\[)]+")
  
  words <- unlist(str_split(words," "))
  words <-  words[!words %in% stopwords::stopwords()] #in stopwords package you have other dictionaries of stopwords
  
  paste0(paste(words,collapse = " "),d) %>% str_remove_all("NA") 
}

tibble(
  original = col_names,
  cleaned = map_chr(col_names,remove_stopwords)
)
  

Output:
 original                                       cleaned                  
  <chr>                                          <chr>                    
1 How old are your parents ?                     old parents ?            
2 How old is your sister ?                       old sister ?             
3 What dessert did you eat yesterday ? [Option1] dessert eat yesterday ? 1
4 What dessert did you eat yesterday ? [Option2] dessert eat yesterday ? 2
5 What dessert did you eat yesterday ? [Option3] dessert eat yesterday ? 3
6 What color is your shirt ? [Option 1]          color shirt ? 1          
7 What color is your shirt ? [Option 2]          color shirt ? 2      

Test case for rename_with()
cleaned_col_names <- 
map_chr(col_names,remove_stopwords)  

df <- 
tibble(
  a = sample(1:10,5),
  b = sample(1:10,5),
  c = sample(1:10,5),
  d = sample(1:10,5),
  e = sample(1:10,5),
  f = sample(1:10,5),
  g = sample(1:10,5)
)
colnames(df) <- col_names
df %>% 
  rename_with(~cleaned_col_names) %>% 
  janitor::clean_names()

Output:
  old_parents old_sister dessert_eat_yesterday_1 dessert_eat_yesterday_2 dessert_eat_yesterday_3 color_shirt_1 color_shirt_2
        <int>      <int>                   <int>                   <int>                   <int>         <int>         <int>
1           9          5                       6                       3                       5             1             4
2           1          7                       1                       5                       9             9             9
3           5          4                       7                      10                       7             6             2
4          10          6                       5                       2                       1            10             5
5           8          8                       4                       8                       6             3             8


Some approaches based on the assumption of having Option plus a number as a pattern.
A way using make.unique, but leaving the first letter of a group unnumbered.
cols <- colnames(data)

make.unique(LETTERS[cumsum(!grepl("Option", cols) | 
              sub(".*(\\d+).*", "\\1", cols) == 1) %% 26], sep="")
[1] "A"  "B"  "C"  "C1" "C2" "D"  "D1"

Another way addressing complete numbering of a group
cols <- colnames(data)

nms <- LETTERS[cumsum(!grepl("Option", cols) | 
         sub(".*(\\d+).*", "\\1", cols) == 1) %% 26]

num <- ifelse(grepl("\\d+", cols), 
                sub(".*(\\d+).*", "\\1", cols), 0)

paste0(nms, replace(num, num == 0, ""))
[1] "A"  "B"  "C1" "C2" "C3" "D1" "D2"

Note: For your 300+ columns you might want to wrap paste0 in another make.unique
make.unique(paste0(nms, replace(num, num == 0, "")), sep="_")

"I was delayed".
Here's my take with Proust's Questionnaire (proust_questions) as toy questions and df_questions as toy data.
This is not a short, Base-R answer by any means!, but it´s really easy to make adjustments inside dplyr::mutate.
# library(tidyverse)
# ------------------

# Creating names
df_new_names <- proust_questions %>% 
  mutate(
    # Cleaning punctuation and the options ("[option ...]")
    question_clean = question %>% 
      str_to_lower() %>% 
      str_remove_all("\\s?\\[option.+\\]$|[^a-z\\s]"),
    
    # Capturing the options numbers inside "[option ... ]"
    option = as.integer(str_extract(question, "\\d+(?=])")),
    
    # It's always good to have unique numeric ids!
    id = 10 * consecutive_id(question_clean),
    
    # Creating question's names as label id 
    # Start your colnames with letters
    question_id_label = paste0(
      "q", 
      str_pad(consecutive_id(question_clean), width = 3, side = "left", pad = 0),
      if_else(
        !is.na(option), 
        paste0("_op", str_pad(option, width = 2, side = "left", pad = 0)), 
        "")),
    
    # Creating question's names as unique text labels
    question_label = map_chr(
      str_split(question_clean, "\\s"), 
      \(x) str_flatten(keep_at(x, c(1:2, length(x))), "_")))

# Checking possibly duplicated "question_label"
df_new_names <- df_new_names %>% 
  left_join(
    df_new_names %>% 
      distinct(question_label, id) %>% 
      count(question_label, sort = TRUE), 
    by = "question_label") %>% 
  mutate(
    question_label = if_else(
      n > 1,
      paste0(question_label, "_q", id),
      question_label),
    
    # Adding option number at "question_label"
    question_label = if_else(
      !is.na(option), 
      paste0(question_label, "_op", option),
      question_label
    )
  ) %>% 

# Just sorting columns
select(id, question, question_id_label, question_label)

The new names (unique ids or names):
> df_new_names
# A tibble: 45 × 4
      id question                                        question_id_label question_label      
   <dbl> <chr>                                           <chr>             <chr>               
 1    10 What is your idea of perfect happiness?         q001              what_is_happiness   
 2    20 What is your greatest fear?                     q002              what_is_fear        
 3    30 What is the trait you most deplore in yourself? q003              what_is_yourself    
 4    40 What is the trait you most deplore in others?   q004              what_is_others      
 5    50 Which living person do you most admire?         q005              which_living_admire 
 6    60 What is your greatest extravagance?             q006              what_is_extravagance
 7    70 What is your current state of mind? [option 1]  q007_op01         what_is_mind_op1    
 8    70 What is your current state of mind? [option 2]  q007_op02         what_is_mind_op2    
 9    70 What is your current state of mind? [option 3]  q007_op03         what_is_mind_op3    
10    80 What do you consider the most overrated virtue? q008              what_do_virtue      
# ℹ 35 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

Now let's rename the questions dataset with unique ids..
# Update with unique ids
df_questions <- df_questions %>% 
  rename_with(
    .cols = intersect(colnames(df_questions), df_new_names$question),
    .fn = \(x) df_new_names$question_id_label[df_new_names$question == x])

> select(df_questions, 1:5)
# A tibble: 3 × 10
  subject_id q001  q002  q003  q004  q005  q006  q007_op01 q007_op02 q007_op03
       <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
1          1 D     B     B     A     E     C     A         B         E        
2          2 A     A     A     B     C     A     A         A         D        
3          3 D     E     A     E     B     C     B         B         E

..or unique text labels:
# Update with text labels
df_questions <- df_questions %>% 
  rename_with(
    .cols = intersect(colnames(df_questions), df_new_names$question),
    .fn = \(x) df_new_names$question_label[df_new_names$question == x])

> select(df_questions, 1:5)
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  subject_id what_is_happiness what_is_fear what_is_yourself what_is_others
       <int> <chr>             <chr>        <chr>            <chr>         
1          1 D                 B            B                A             
2          2 A                 A            A                B             
3          3 D                 E            A                E             

The toy data:
# -------------------------
df_questions <- structure(
  list(
    subject_id = 1:3, 
    `What is your idea of perfect happiness?` = c("D", "A", "D"), 
    `What is your greatest fear?` = c("B", "A", "E"), 
    `What is the trait you most deplore in yourself?` = c("B", "A", "A"), 
    `What is the trait you most deplore in others?` = c("A", "B", "E"), 
    `Which living person do you most admire?` = c("E", "C", "B"), 
    `What is your greatest extravagance?` = c("C", "A", "C"), 
    `What is your current state of mind? [option 1]` = c("A", "A", "B"), 
    `What is your current state of mind? [option 2]` = c("B", "A", "B"), 
    `What is your current state of mind? [option 3]` = c("E", "D", "E"), 
    `What do you consider the most overrated virtue?` = c("A", "B", "A"), 
    `On what occasion do you lie?` = c("E", "D", "A" ), 
    `What do you most dislike about your appearance?` = c("A", "D", "B"), 
    `Which living person do you most despise?` = c("C", "B", "E"), 
    `What is the quality you most like in a man?` = c("C", "C", "D"), 
    `What is the quality you most like in a woman?` = c("D", "D", "E"), 
    `Which words or phrases do you most overuse?` = c("B", "A", "A"), 
    `What or who is the greatest love of your life? [option 1]` = c("B", "E", "D"), 
    `What or who is the greatest love of your life? [option 2]` = c("D", "E", "D"), 
    `What or who is the greatest love of your life? [option 3]` = c("B", "B", "A"), 
    `When and where were you happiest?` = c("C", "D", "A"), 
    `Which talent would you most like to have? [option 1]` = c("A", "C", "A"), 
    `Which talent would you most like to have? [option 2]` = c("A", "C", "E"), 
    `Which talent would you most like to have? [option 3]` = c("E", "D", "E"), 
    `If you could change one thing about yourself, what would it be?` = c("C", "C", "D"), 
    `What do you consider your greatest achievement?` = c("A", "B", "D"), 
    `If you were to die and come back as a person or a thing, what would it be?` = c("C", "C", "C"), 
    `Where would you most like to live?` = c("A", "E", "D"), 
    `What is your most treasured possession?` = c("C", "B", "B"), 
    `What do you regard as the lowest depth of misery?` = c("A", "B", "D"), 
    `What is your favorite occupation?` = c("C", "E", "D"), 
    `What is your most marked characteristic?` = c("B", "B", "C"), 
    `What do you most value in your friends?` = c("A", "B", "D"), 
    `Who are your favorite writers?` = c("B", "B", "B"), 
    `Who is your hero of fiction? [option 1]` = c("E", "E", "E"), 
    `Who is your hero of fiction? [option 2]` = c("B", "D", "C"), 
    `Who is your hero of fiction? [option 3]` = c("E", "B", "B"), 
    `Which historical figure do you most identify with?` = c("D", "C", "A"), 
    `Who are your heroes in real life?` = c("A", "A", "B"), 
    `What are your favorite names? [option 1]` = c("A", "B", "C"), 
    `What are your favorite names? [option 2]` = c("C", "A", "A"), 
    `What are your favorite names? [option 3]` = c("C", "C", "D"), 
    `What is it that you most dislike?` = c("B", "A", "B"), 
    `What is your greatest regret?` = c("E", "C", "E"), 
    `How would you like to die?` = c("B", "A", "C"), 
    `What is your motto?` = c("C", "E", "E")), 
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
  row.names = c(NA, -3L))

# -------------------------
proust_questions <- tibble::tribble(
  ~question,
  "What is your idea of perfect happiness?",
  "What is your greatest fear?",
  "What is the trait you most deplore in yourself?",
  "What is the trait you most deplore in others?",
  "Which living person do you most admire?",
  "What is your greatest extravagance?",
  "What is your current state of mind? [option 1]",
  "What is your current state of mind? [option 2]",
  "What is your current state of mind? [option 3]",
  "What do you consider the most overrated virtue?",
  "On what occasion do you lie?",
  "What do you most dislike about your appearance?",
  "Which living person do you most despise?",
  "What is the quality you most like in a man?",
  "What is the quality you most like in a woman?",
  "Which words or phrases do you most overuse?",
  "What or who is the greatest love of your life? [option 1]",
  "What or who is the greatest love of your life? [option 2]",
  "What or who is the greatest love of your life? [option 3]",
  "When and where were you happiest?",
  "Which talent would you most like to have? [option 1]",
  "Which talent would you most like to have? [option 2]",
  "Which talent would you most like to have? [option 3]",
  "If you could change one thing about yourself, what would it be?",
  "What do you consider your greatest achievement?",
  "If you were to die and come back as a person or a thing, what would it be?",
  "Where would you most like to live?",
  "What is your most treasured possession?",
  "What do you regard as the lowest depth of misery?",
  "What is your favorite occupation?",
  "What is your most marked characteristic?",
  "What do you most value in your friends?",
  "Who are your favorite writers?",
  "Who is your hero of fiction? [option 1]",
  "Who is your hero of fiction? [option 2]",
  "Who is your hero of fiction? [option 3]",
  "Which historical figure do you most identify with?",
  "Who are your heroes in real life?",
  "What are your favorite names? [option 1]",
  "What are your favorite names? [option 2]",
  "What are your favorite names? [option 3]",
  "What is it that you most dislike?",
  "What is your greatest regret?",
  "How would you like to die?",
  "What is your motto?")

